# Adding vector initialization to struct constructor

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct which is as follows:

```
struct octNode{
octNode* parent;
octNode* child[8];
std::vector<int> pointIndex;
//constructor of the struct
octNode()
{ 
      memset(parent,0,sizeof(parent));
      memset(child,0,sizeof(child));
}
};
```

But this throws a run-time error: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcdcd.
Unhandled exception at 0x771115de in Octree_octnode_0113.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcdcd.

The access violation occurs in the creation of the empty vector. Is there a way to initialize the vector in the constructor so that the error doesnt occur?

Comment: `parent` isn't pointing anywhere and it isn't initialized. How did you expect this to make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following

```
  memset(parent,0,sizeof(parent));
```

you are passing an uninitialized pointer to `memset()`. Did you mean to say:

```
  memset(&parent, 0, sizeof(parent));
```

or, quite simply

```
  parent = NULL; // or nullptr
```

?

Comment: The line for `child` is correct in the OP's code, since that's an array of pointers.  Most likely, the initialization of `parent` should just be setting it to `NULL` (which can be done in the initialization list).

Answer (score 2):

This line causes the use of an uninitialized pointer:

```
memset(parent,0,sizeof(parent));
```

You should just set it to `NULL` instead:

```
parent = NULL;
```

(Or better yet, do so in the initialization list:)

```
octNode() : parent(NULL)
{ 
      memset(child,0,sizeof(child));
}
```

Comment: why no initializer list for child?

Comment: @MooingDuck To my knowledge, an array cannot have its elements initialized in an initializer list prior to C++11. Plus, that would be `child{NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}` which is verbose and fragile (changing the length of the `child` array would render the initialization incomplete).  Of course, an `std::vector` would be better than an array.

Comment: `:child()` works in C++03 and C++11 both.  Exactly the same as `new T[2]` is default-initialized, but `new T[2]()` is value-initialized: http://ideone.com/3Paskj

Comment: @MooingDuck Then that would work too, yes.  (However, the answer to the question is "you are initializing `parent` wrong," so in that respect the initialization style of `child` is noteworthy, but not directly related.)

Comment: Yeah, it's not directly related to the question, but I thought it was noteworthy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Code should say:

```
struct octNode{
    octNode* parent;
    octNode* child[8];
    std::vector<int> pointIndex;
    //constructor of the struct
    octNode()
    : parent(NULL) // maybe nullptr ?
    , pointIndex()
    { 
        std::fill_n(child, 8, NULL); // nullptr?
    }
};
```

Comment: child can also be default constructed like pointindex, it will fill the array with null values